# preg_replace: bad regex == 'Unknown Modifier'?

Tags: php, regex, warnings, preg-replace

I'm making up fake email addresses and I just want to make sure they are in a valid email format so I'm trying to remove any character that is not in the set below:

```
$jusr['email'] = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9.-_@]/g', '', $jusr['email']);
```

I haven't had any trouble on my windows machine, but on the linux dev server I get this error each time this code runs:

```
Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier 'g' in /var/www/vhosts/....
```

I think it's the regex string, but I can't pin it down.  Little help?  Thanks.

**Clarification:** I'm not trying to accommodate all valid email addresses (unnecessary for my purpose), I just need to figure out what's wrong with my preg_replace regex.

Comment: As an aside, '+' is valid in email addresses and used frequently by gmail users.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`g` is not a valid modifier in PCRE (the regex implementation PHP uses) because it's simply not needed; `preg_replace()` will perform global replacements by default. You'll find the modifier in true Perl regex as well as JavaScript regex, but not in PCRE.

Just drop the `g`:

```
$jusr['email'] = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9.-_@]/', '', $jusr['email']);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have an invalid PCRE modifier. Here is the list of valid PCRE modifiers:

http://us.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

The `g` (global) modifier is **on by default**, so you don't need it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `g` is not a [valid PCRE modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).  Try looking at [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to /g, the inner part of your regexp doesn't seem to be valid either:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9.-_@]
```

First, the "^" (which is start-of-input metachar) makes no sense inside [...] (unless you allow email adresses that contain "^"). Second, the dash should be escaped or put to the end of the group, otherwise it will be treated as range operator. And most important, your expression disallows a wide range of perfectly valid email addresses. Check some [examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses).

Comment: `[^...]` means anything that is not `[...]`. But good catch on the `.-_`.

Comment: Good eye, thanks. As for the fact that this disallows lots of valid email addresses, that's not a concern for me.  In this case, it's just easier to supply a fake email that will never be used than correct the Joomla api.