# preg_replace confusion

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

In a string containing some html I want to find and replace every occurrence of a `<h1-6>` tag, including anything that follows it, up until another `<h1-6>` tag or until the end of the html string.

My pattern: `<h\d.+?(?=<h\d)`

With /gs flags this pattern works fine on [this online testing tool](https://regex101.com/r/eY7wS9/12).

However, on server side test I am only able to make my pattern match the first occurrence, while the rest are being ignored.

[PHP Manual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653055/preg-replace-bad-regex-unknown-modifier) states:

> Searches subject for matche**s** to pattern and replaces **them** with
>   replacement.

[Another post answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653055/preg-replace-bad-regex-unknown-modifier) mentions:

> preg_replace() will perform global replacements by default

According to the above, my server side pattern should work if changed to `/<h\d.+?(?=<h\d)/s`, but for some reason it still only replaces the first occurrence.

Full code:

```
$html = get_html_string();
$pattern = '/<h\d.+?(?=<h\d)/s';
$replace = '<div>$0</div>';
$html = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $html);
return $html;
```

---

**Update:**

Looks like my html example somehow differs from actual html on the website. Because of this I made sure to copy the string that i want to manipulate directly in to the online tester tool. Now it is apparent that matching works but the actual problem was that last match is not included. See [this updated test](https://regex101.com/r/ixacji/3).

Thanks to Nick for the answer and everyone else for chiming in.

Comment: in this example u  are not targting only h2

Comment: if i really understand , you want to find all occurences with this format <h*>*</h*>

Comment: For me, it should work. Please, show us sample input.

Comment: Turns out that sample input was somehow different. I update my post with details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of issues:

1. You need the `g` (global) flag to get multiple matches
2. You need to add `$` (end-of-string) as an alternation to your lookahead so that it can match up to the end of string from the last `<hn>` tag.

This should do what you want:

```
<h\d.+?(?=<h\d|$)
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eY7wS9/11)

In PHP:

```
preg_match_all('/<h\d.+?(?=<h\d|$)/s', $html, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <h1> attribute="whatever">asiponfpweg ihnasegio</h1>asd
<p>whatever</p>
<img src=""></img>
    [1] => <h3> attribute="whatever">asiponfpweg ihnasegio</h3>
<p>whatever</p>
<p>whatever</p>
    [2] => <h1><span> attribute="whatever">asiponfpweg ihnasegio</span></h3>
<p>whatever</p>
    [3] => <h3> attribute="whatever">asiponfpweg ihnasegio</h3>
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/oZXAF)

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am trying to make this work with preg_replace. I have rewritten my question.

Comment: @bewww sorry about lack of response - it's been night time here. I guess you've got it resolved, but the same regex works fine with `preg_replace`, see https://3v4l.org/K8h0P